# How does C determine bound of array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm studying arrays on C. Currently, I'm running this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

signed char cData[][2][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

int main() 
{
    printf("%d\n", cData[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

And the answer is `4210700`.
I want to know how does [c](/questions/tagged/c) determine the first bound?
And how come I get the number `4210700` instead of `1`?

Comment: If the array is characters then why do you tell printf to interpret it as 32bit integers?

Comment: It does not matter as it paased to the printf as integer.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to do `cData[0][0][0]`? Otherwise the code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Did you get any compilation warnings?

Comment: yeah, sorry. I forgot about that. I was testing with 2d array then I try to create an array with unknown first bound and forget to fix the printf argument. With [0][0][0], I get the answer 1. As I figure out, C doesn't seem to determine the number of the first bound. But still don't know why does cData[0][0] returns 4210700. Can you explain it? Thanks

Comment: Also, using wrong format specifier leads to undefined behaviour

Comment: @n.m. no I didn't. I run the code on cmd with MinGW compiler. Oh, and I get it that 4210700 is the address.

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc As the answers (one of which you accepted) indicate, `cData[0][0]` is a pointer, so 4210700 is simply a base10 representation of some memory address. But as also pointed out in the answers, the way you are printing it out is undefined behavior, so that number could be anything. The correct way to `printf` this pointer is in the accepted answer.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the latest version. At the very least pass `-Wall` option to the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cData[0][0]` is basically a pointer (`signed char *` type) and you need `%p` specifier.

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)cData[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

This declaration

```
signed char cData[][2][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

is an aggregate declaration. You can rewrite it the following way

```
typedef signed char T[2][3];
T cData[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

In turn the type `T` is a type of an aggregate. Its members have type `signed char[3].`

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 17 Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current
>   object. When no designations are present, **subobjects of the current
>   object are initialized in order according to the type of the current
>   object**: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union...

and

> 20 If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are
>   aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the
>   subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a
>   subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the
>   initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace
>   initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the
>   contained union.  **Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list
>   are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate
>   or the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers
>   are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of
>   which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.**

So at first the most inner aggregate of the type `signed char[3]` is initialized. Then the second member of the aggregate of the type `signed char[2][3]` is initialized. In turn it is a member of the aggregate of the type `signed char [][2][3]`. So there is only one initializer for one member of this aggregate.

As result `cDara` will have type `signed char[1][2][3]`.

The expressions `cData[0][0]` has the type `signed char [3]` that is implicitly converted in the function call to the pointer to its first element.

So in this statement

```
printf("%d\n", cData[0][0]);
```

you are trying to output the address as `signed int` that in general has undefined behavior.

If you want to output the first element as an integer you should write

```
printf("%d\n", cData[0][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about one pair of brackets

```
     printf("%d\n", cData[0][0][0]);
```

How the  initialisation works: First dimension is filled then second and third. Depending on numbers of initialised and braces the minimum required is determined

Comment: Normally, 'braces' refers to 'curly brackets', `{}`, and not to square brackets `[]`.  I've never heard of square brackets being called braces.  Round brackets `()` are also called parentheses, and square brackets are sometimes just called brackets (and `<>` are sometimes called 'angle brackets').